# Google map not correctly center

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a problem with Google map.
I have multiple marker, div and infowindows. It work but, when i refresh map in my nav, i would like the map center in Paris. But, it's not center in Paris but nearby in. Marker Paris is at left top and i would like marker at center.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var map;
var paris = new google.maps.LatLng(48.8566667, 2.3509871);
var tunis = new google.maps.LatLng(36.845235, 10.164723);
var hongkong = new google.maps.LatLng(22.298812, 114.172175);



function Tunisie(controlDiv2, map) {

  controlDiv2.style.padding = '5px';

  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = '';
  controlDiv2.appendChild(controlUI);

  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<b></b>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(tunis);
  });

}
function HongKong(controlDiv3, map) {
  controlDiv3.style.padding = '5px';

  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = '';
  controlDiv3.appendChild(controlUI);

  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<b></b>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(hongkong);
  });

}
function Paris(controlDiv, map) {

  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = '';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<b></b>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(paris);
  });

}

function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom: 8,
    zoomControl : false,                       
    scrollwheel : false,                      
    disableDoubleClickZoom : true          
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);


  var tunisieControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var tunisieControl = new Tunisie(tunisieControlDiv, map);

  tunisieControlDiv.index = 3;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(tunisieControlDiv);

  var hongkongControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var hongkongControl = new HongKong(hongkongControlDiv, map);

  hongkongControlDiv.index = 2;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(hongkongControlDiv);

 var parisControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var parisControl = new Paris(parisControlDiv, map);

  parisControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(parisControlDiv);

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: tunis,
      map: map,
      title: ''
  });

    var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: hongkong,
      map: map,
      title: ''
  });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      center: paris,
      position: paris,
      map: map,
      title: ''
  });

    var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ""
  });
    var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ""
  });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: ""
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker2.getPosition());
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker3.getPosition());
  });  
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });

    infowindow2.open(map,marker2);
    infowindow3.open(map,marker3);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thx for your help, i searching in google but i have'nt find any informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want the map to be initialized centered on Paris, use that for the `center` [MapOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) (not the center property of a marker).

```
function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: paris,
        zoom: 8,
        zoomControl: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
```

- the infowindow "auto pan" is interferring with the map center (you are opening 3 infowindows, one right after another, the pans are interfering with each other.  Add `{disableAutoPan: true}` to the infowindow options.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3Lab468/2/)

working code snippet:

```js
var map;
var paris = new google.maps.LatLng(48.8566667, 2.3509871);
var tunis = new google.maps.LatLng(36.845235, 10.164723);
var hongkong = new google.maps.LatLng(22.298812, 114.172175);



function Tunisie(controlDiv2, map) {

  controlDiv2.style.padding = '5px';

  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = '';
  controlDiv2.appendChild(controlUI);

  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<b></b>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(tunis);
  });

}

function HongKong(controlDiv3, map) {
  controlDiv3.style.padding = '5px';

  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = '';
  controlDiv3.appendChild(controlUI);

  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<b></b>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(hongkong);
  });

}

function Paris(controlDiv, map) {

  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlUI.style.borderWidth = '2px';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = '';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';
  controlText.innerHTML = '<b></b>';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(paris);
  });

}

function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: paris,
    zoom: 8,
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);


  var tunisieControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var tunisieControl = new Tunisie(tunisieControlDiv, map);

  tunisieControlDiv.index = 3;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(tunisieControlDiv);

  var hongkongControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var hongkongControl = new HongKong(hongkongControlDiv, map);

  hongkongControlDiv.index = 2;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(hongkongControlDiv);

  var parisControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var parisControl = new Paris(parisControlDiv, map);

  parisControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(parisControlDiv);

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: tunis,
    map: map,
    title: 'Tunis'
  });

  var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: hongkong,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hong Kong'
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: paris,
    map: map,
    title: 'Paris'
  });

  var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Tunis",
    disableAutoPan: true

  });
  var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Hong Kong",
    disableAutoPan: true

  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Paris",
    disableAutoPan: true
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker2.getPosition());
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker3.getPosition());
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });

  infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
  infowindow3.open(map, marker3);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 102 of your code.  That's where you set the center of the map.
Var paris is global, so you can use that anywhere.

```
....
function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: paris,   // I would like the map center in Paris
    zoom: 8,
    zoomControl : false,                       
    scrollwheel : false,                      
    disableDoubleClickZoom : true          
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
...
```

EDIT:
By the way, this value gives you the Louvre.  Nice place, well in the center.

```
var paris = new google.maps.LatLng(48.8610174, 2.3358584);  // Louvre
```

Comment: Thx for you response
It not work correctely, beacause it's not center in paris. Marker Paris is at left top and i would like marker at center.

Comment: Okay, do you have a specific point (address, monument, park, ...) in mind?  I'll give you the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to give a tip, since this idea didn´t come naturally to me:

I used the latitude and longitude from "https://www.google.se/maps/" fully zoomed and it works fine there but when using those on my home page it threw them off by some 0.001 (about 50 meters away from the building, enough to fool visitors)

I tweaked the latitude and longitude by hand for a couple of minutes until I got it right and it both centered and put the marker in the correct spot.